# How to change column type from string to integer? Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, types, enums, database-migration

I have a column called `owner_type` in a table called `events`. This column is filled with one of two values: 0 (signalling regular users) and 1 (for business users).

This column has a data type `string`, I'd like to change it to `integer` given that it'll always contain 0s and 1s. So I did this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('owner_type')->change()->default(0);
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('owner_type')->default(0)->change();
    });
}
```

However, I receive this error:

> n AbstractPlatform.php line 461:
>
> Unknown database type enum requested,
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL57Platform may not support it.

In the migration that created `events` I have:

```
    $table->enum('**', ['**', '**'])->default('**');
    $table->enum('status', ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'])->default('*');
```

However, this table is already migrated. So what's wrong?

Comment: From the docs: "Only the following column types can be "changed": bigInteger, binary, boolean, date, dateTime, dateTimeTz, decimal, integer, json, longText, mediumText, smallInteger, string, text, time, unsignedBigInteger, unsignedInteger and unsignedSmallInteger." The migration probably fails because it detects the enum fields and then stops working to prevent messing up the database. Also, obligatory anti-enum: http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/

Comment: This solution solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42107554/7979661

Comment: Ah nice, didn't know about that!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    public function up()
{
    //
    Schema::table('events', function($table) {
        $table->string('owner_type')->default(0);
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    //
    Schema::table('events', function($table) {
        $table->dropColumn('owner_type');
    });
}
```