# Laravel migration uknown database enum requested

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

Live application have order table.

```
    Schema::create('order', function($table){

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->dateTime('date')->nullable();

        $table->enum('status', array('CREATED','FINISHED'))->default('CREATED');
    });
```

Now I need to update status field in that table, but I want to save old data in database. So I created one more migration which will update status field in order table.

```
    Schema::table('order', function($table){
        $table->enum('status', array('CREATED','FINISHED','CLOSED'))->default('CREATED')->change();
    });
```

But when i run `php artisan migrate` I got error saying `Unknow database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBal\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may not support it.`

Comment: From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#modifying-columns): "_Only the following column types can be "changed": bigInteger, binary, boolean, date, dateTime, dateTimeTz, decimal, integer, json, longText, mediumText, smallInteger, string, text, time, unsignedBigInteger, unsignedInteger and unsignedSmallInteger._" and also "_Renaming any column in a table that also has a column of type enum is not currently supported._"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.1 Unknown database type enum requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140860/laravel-5-1-unknown-database-type-enum-requested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use facade of query builder to achieve the same,

```
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE order CHANGE COLUMN status status  
ENUM('CREATED', 'FINISHED', 'CLOSED') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CREATED'");
```

By raw migration it is not possible,

> **NOTE:-** Only the following column types can be "changed": bigInteger, binary, boolean, date, dateTime, dateTimeTz, decimal,
>   integer, json, longText, mediumText, smallInteger, string, text, time,
>   unsignedBigInteger, unsignedInteger and unsignedSmallInteger.