# How to change column data type in laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I am trying to change column data type using laravel 5.6.

I have a table in which two columns have a data type of `text` but I would like to change it to `longtext`. I have tried following:

- executed `composer require doctrine/dbal`
- executed `composer dump-autoload`

...and then created the migration `2019_12_23_065820_change_response_column_data_type_in_log_requests_table.php` for `log_requests` table.

...and then the following script

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('log_requests', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->longText('request')->nullable()->change();
        $table->longText('response')->nullable()->change();
    });
}
```

But it is not changing the column's data type. Can someone guide me? Where am I wrong so that I can fix it? Thank you.

**EDITED**

After requesting for migration in comment, I added migration script:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('log_requests', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->string('api_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('url')->nullable();
        $table->string('method')->nullable();
        $table->string('ip_address')->nullable();
        $table->string('status_code')->nullable();
        $table->string('duration')->nullable();
        $table->text('request')->nullable();
        $table->text('response')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you getting any error ?

Comment: @YasinPatel no there is no error, but it does not changing the column type

Comment: @ImranAbbas how do u know it isn't changed, did u describe the table in mysql?

Comment: What's the underlying database?

Comment: @TsaiKoga I checked the through `phpmyadmin` the column data type is still `text`

Comment: @ImranAbbas have you run `php artisan migrate`

Comment: @apokryfos I am using Apache Mysql `mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev`

Comment: @TsaiKoga off course, yes 100% sure I did executed and test many times as well after roll backing

Comment: I'm sure this will solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140860/laravel-5-1-unknown-database-type-enum-requested/42107554#42107554

Comment: @SatendraRawat that question is different one

Comment: @apokryfos any idea please, how can i fix it?

Comment: no idea. This code should work. You will need some more extensive debugging like dumping the SQL log (described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753868/how-to-get-the-query-executed-in-laravel-5-dbgetquerylog-returning-empty-ar)

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you, I am still trying and looking for solution

Comment: Can you also share the migration that creates `log_requests`?

Comment: @apokryfos I did it, kindly check it.

Comment: I've tried making a fresh laravel project with the default migrations plus the "create" table migration. Then I added the altering migration. Everything seems to have worked fine for me. I don't know what might be but it's probably something very case specific. If @N69S answer worked for you I'd go for that one and call it a day

Answer (score 4):

Just change the column comment, for example:

```
$table->mediumText('myColumn')->comment(' ')->change(); // up
$table->text('myColumn')->comment('')->change(); // down
```

Comment: I want to convert it into longText not medium

Comment: Okey, replace your type with mediumText. just add comment

Comment: I encounter with same issue and test this code and it works! This answer should be accepted.

Comment: @ImranAbbas Do you test this solution?

Comment: @ImranAbbas just change it to longText then, have u try that?  The key of this answer is to change the comment section to be a space

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with how doctorine treats texts, it doesn't differentiate long medium or normal text however it's doable by changing the size attribute.

`$table->string('request', 4294967295)->change();`

as per @andfelzapata in the issue https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9636

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using Dbal if you go for the direct query

```php
public function up()
{
    \DB::statement('alter table log_requests modify request longtext null;');
    \DB::statement('alter table log_requests modify response longtext null;');
}

public function down()
{
    \DB::statement('alter table log_requests modify request text null;');
    \DB::statement('alter table log_requests modify response text null;');
}
```

Comment: What's wrong if I am using `$table->longText('request')`. It is laravel docs

Comment: @ImranAbbas Nothing is wrong with it, when you create the table. but when you want to alter it, it gets more complicated.

Comment: I tried, it is returning following error `SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right tru
ncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'value' at row 1 (SQL: ALTER TABLE system_
logs CHANGE value value VARCHAR(190) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL COLLATE `utf
8mb4_unicode_ci`)
`

Comment: i dont know where you're getting that error or how that query is related to my answer. `ALTER TABLE system_ logs` & `varchar(190)`, my answer was about `log_requests` & `longtext` ... @ImranAbbas . in any case, when altering column type, it is usual to adapt the values to the new format before or simultaneously.

Comment: Why you are using plain SQL syntax here? I think this should be done via ORM

Comment: @mhrabiee to avoid having to load doctrine/dbal to alter tables in migration.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with the help of this function. You can create a new migration and change column type

```
public function up()
{
Schema::table('log_requests', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->longText('request')->change();
    $table->longText('response')->change();
});
```

You need to install doctrine/dbal to make this work

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```