# Why php migration fails on change table column type to string from numeric

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, migration

I am new to PHP and laravel platform,need your help to resolve PDOException on run the migration task to alter table column type from number to string.

```
...
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('BuildTable', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->string('snapshot_id')->change();
    });

}
....
```

getting PDOException on run the migration task

```
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[0A000]: Feature not supported: 7 ERROR:  unimplemented: type conversion from INT8 to VARCHAR(255) requires overwriting existing values which is not yet implemented
HINT:  You have attempted to use a feature that is not yet implemented.
```

Existing table structure was created using

```
      Schema::create(
        $this->tablename,
        function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('account_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('snapshot_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps(6);
            $table->softDeletes('deleted_at', 6)->default(null);
        }
    );
```

The existing table already have data in snapshot_id

Php version is 7.3.20 running on linux mint OS , Database - cockroachDB

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940495/laravel-migration-table-fields-type-change/40047800

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change column data type in laravel 5.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59451801/how-to-change-column-data-type-in-laravel-5-6)

Comment: Chris , the details didn't resolve the issue , I am getting "SQLSTATE[0A000]: Feature not supported: 7 ERROR:  unimplemented: type conversion from INT8 to VARCHAR(255) requires overwriting existing values which is not yet implemented

Comment: I think the error message is fairly self explanatory. Your table already contains data which has been stored as `INT8` and you're asking the engine to convert to `VARCHAR(255)` which it doesn't know how to do. If the table were empty of data it would be different. Why do you want to convert what looks to be a foreign key to a string anyway?

Comment: This looks like an issue with your database rather than Laravel since the error message is actually from your database itself. Which database you're using? Please the details in your post.

Comment: @sykez @ Unflux You are correct,Its a database related issue as I am getting similar exception on direct SQL execution in tool too.  We are using cockroachDB and it looks like direct data conversion from INT8 to VARCHAR feature not available  for this particular version of it

Answer (score 2):

This feature will be experimentally available in CockroachDB v20.2, which is getting released later this year.

If you want, you can test out with an alpha version (v20.2.0-alpha.2) which has this functionality. See the [release notes](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/releases/v20.2.0-alpha.1.html). To use it, you need to set the following session variable: `SET enable_experimental_alter_column_type_general = true;`