# Adding new enum type to the existing enum column in Laravel migration

Tags: laravel, enums, migration, laravel-migrations

I am developing a Laravel application. What I am trying to do now is that I am trying to add a new enum type to the existing enum column.

This is how enum column is created/ migrated in the first place.

```
$table->enum('type', [BlogType::IMAGE, BlogType::TEXT]);
```

Now I am trying to add a new enum type to that column creating a new migration like this.

```
Schema::table('blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->enum('type', [BlogType::IMAGE, BlogType::TEXT, BlogType::VIDEO])->change();
        });
```

As you can see, I added a VIDEO blog type.

When I run the migration, I got the following error.

```
 Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may not support it.
```

Then I came across this link, [Laravel 5.1 Unknown database type enum requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140860/laravel-5-1-unknown-database-type-enum-requested).

I tried adding the following in the constructor of the migration class.

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::getDoctrineSchemaManager()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
```

Then I got the following error when I run the migration.

```
Unknown column type "enum" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap(). If this error occurs during database introspection then you might have forgotten to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use AbstractPlatform#registerDoctrineTypeMapping() or have your custom types implement Type#getMappedDatabaseTypes(). If the type name is empty you might have a problem with the cache or forgot some mapping information.
```

Now I am not renaming the column, I am just adding the new supported enum value. What would be the best solution and how can I do that, pelase?

Comment: Have you tried running it as raw queries instead of using DBAL, take a look at this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32967177/1457270

Comment: this doesnt answer your question but you might want to use `TINYINT` instead, I personally dont like the `ENUM` column because of the way you need to define your options. With tinyint you can just use 0 to 128 (or 0 to 255 when unsigned) and resolve the integer to a string within php.

Comment: I do not want to use the explicit SQL query statement. That's why. What would be the better approach?

Answer (score 0):

For now, we have only one solution: RAW query

```
public function up()
{
    DB::statement('
        ALTER TABLE `blogs` CHANGE COLUMN `type` `type` 
        ENUM("'.implode([BlogType::IMAGE, BlogType::TEXT, BlogType::VIDEO], '", "').'")
        NOT NULL
        DEFAULT "'.BlogType::IMAGE.'"
    ');
}
```

Where `blogs` is table name and `type` column name.