# Cannot change column type from `date` to `dateTime`

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime, migration

I want to change the column type of a column in a table in my database from `date` to `dateTime`, because I need the time as well. The table already has values in many rows for the column `purchased_at`.
For that, I created the following migration:

```
public function up() {
    Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dateTime('purchased_at')->nullable()->change();
    });
}

public function down() {
    Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->date('purchased_at')->nullable()->change();
    });
}
```

When I run `php artisan migrate`, I get this error:

> Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException  : Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL80Platform may not support it.

We're using MySQL 5.7 which *does* know both `enum` (as mentioned in the error, although I haven't mentioned that in the migration) and `dateTime`. I tried to add a field to the table, instead of changing an existing field and that migration went well:

```
$table->dateTime('purchased_at_2')->nullable();
```

---

Any idea, why I cannot change the column type from `date` to `dateTime`?

Comment: Changing a column type requires it to be ALTERed. Check user permissions also.

Comment: Yes, so what's the issue?

Comment: I don't know. I don't know Laravel so I won't be of much help in that area. You can try and ALTER it in phpmyadmin.

Comment: This is an in-production app, so I'd rather not touch the database manually.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Note that you can use `DB::statement` to run queries directly against the database instead of using PHPMyAdmin (which shouldn't be installed on a production server anyway) or the console.

Comment: We're using Laravel 5.7

Comment: I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29174204/3397217) that says no column can be changed in a table that has an enum in it, which my `orders` table *does* have; hence that weird error about the `enum`...Is that the issue?

Comment: Huh, that does sound like the issue. You might be able to do the ALTER command in a DB::statement, then.

Comment: Yep, that did it. You can post that as an answer if you'd like, linking to the post I've linked to and I'll accept it.

Comment: It should be closed as a duplicate then. @LinusGeffarth